# How to acess queue stats (size and waiting time) on service block?

Tags: anylogic

I am a Simul8 user. And now I´m learning anylogic.

I need to collect metrics for Service Blocks in my model: average waiting time and average number waiting.
How to acess this metrics ?

I only could acess the *myService.queueSize()*.

I also try *myService.sieze.queue.statsSize.mean()* as someone suggest on stackoverflow. But I got the following msg: *sieze cannot be resolved or is not a field.*

Thanks in advance.

[Error IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p17aO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the queue within a `Service` object by calling `myService.queue`. Same goes for the buildin in Delay: `myService.delay`

Now you have all API calls that you get with normal Queue and Delay objects.

Note that average waiting time and average number waiting is something you will need to collect manually, though. But that is a different question :)

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. 

I get an error by calling "service.queue.xxx". Is there any trick ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p17aO.png

Comment: true, `queue` does not seem to work. In that case, easiest workaround is to use a separate Queue element before the service (make sure to set the Service queue capacity to 1 so it is not really used and everyone queues in the separate queue element)